# Moving data from one column to another in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, move

Sometimes, one might want to *move* some data from one column to another.  By *moving* (in constrast to *copying*), I mean that the new column was originally null before doing the operation, and the old column should be set to null after doing the operation.

I have a table defined as such:

`CREATE TABLE photos(id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, photo1 BYTEA, photo2 BYTEA);`

Suppose there is an entry in the table where `photo1` contains some data, and `photo2` is `NULL`.  I would like to make an `UPDATE` query wuch that `photo1` becomes `NULL` and `photo2` contains the data that was originally in `photo1`.

I issue the following SQL command (`WHERE` clause left out for brevity):

`UPDATE photos SET photo2 = photo1, photo1 = NULL;`

It seems to work.

I also tried it this way:

`UPDATE photos SET photo1 = NULL, photo2 = photo1;`

It also seems to work.

But is it guaranteed to work?  Specifically, could `photo1` be set to `NULL` *before* `photo2` is set to `photo1`, thereby causing me to end up with `NULL` in both columns?

As an aside, this standard `UPDATE` syntax seems inefficient when my `BYTEA`s are large, as `photo2` has to be copied byte-by-byte from `photo1`, when a simple swapping of pointers might have sufficed.  Maybe there is a more efficient way that I don't know about?

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed to work (and required by the SQL standard)

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely safe.

Column-references in the `UPDATE` refer to the *old* columns, not the new values. There is in fact no way to reference a computed new value from another column.

See, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE x (a integer, b integer);
INSERT INTO x (a,b) VALUES (1,1), (2,2);

UPDATE x SET a = a + 1, b = a + b;
```

results in

```
test=> SELECT * FROM x;
 a | b 
---+---
 2 | 2
 3 | 4
```

... and the ordering of assignments is not significant. If you try to multiply-assign a value, you'll get

```
test=> UPDATE x SET a = a + 1, a = a + 1;
ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "a"
```

because it makes no sense to assign to the same column multiple times, given that both expressions reference the old tuple values, and order is not significant.

However, to avoid a full table rewrite in this case, I would just `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... RENAME ...` then `CREATE` the new column with the old name.

Comment: Thanks, this should allay my fears of non-deterministic behavior.  Regarding the column renaming, I can't do that because it's not a full table rewrite.  When I said "`WHERE` clause left out for brevity" I mean that there's a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement that I omitted (and hence not all rows will be affected).  Maybe I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: I agree with @Jacobm001's now-deleted post's comment that what you're doing is a bit weird in terms of moving data from column to column. I'd normalise to a side-table instead and update the referencing FK to the new photo.

Comment: I didn't see the comment before the post was deleted and I don't have enough reputation to see deleted comments. Could you please elaborate on why using a side-table would be better, and whether I should be doing this for just large data (like `BYTEA`) or for small text fields as well?

Comment: @Bernard Because of the automatic out-of-line storage done by [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) it's not very significant for efficiency; the data won't get copied when you do this. So it's mostly a matter of "clean feeling" database design. Your design isn't wrong, it's just not how I think I'd prefer to do it, and yours may have performance advantages. Don't worry.